# Object.create not running constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an instance of a class within a static method, I am doing it with `Object.create(this.prototype)` which seems to work, however, my property `items` is `undefined` when I log it to the console.

I have this class called model which is the base:

```
export default class model {

  protected items: any = {}

  public constructor(options: ModelSettings) {
    // Do some stuff
    // Does not set the property items before it is compiled
  }

  public static create(options) {
    let t = Object.create(this.prototype) as any
    console.log(t.items)
  }
}
```

I then have this class purchases which extends the model:

```
export default class purchases extends model {
  public constructor() {
    super({table: 'purchases'})
  }
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
purchases.create({ my: 'options' })
```

The create method the creates an instance of `purchases` which seems to work, however the property `items` is `undefined` like I previously stated above.

Is `Object.create()` not running the constructor?

Comment: Why don't you use `new model()` instead of `object.create` ? `new model()` will definitely call the constructor

Comment: Because I don't want a new `model`, I want a new `purchases`, then I want to set some some extra "setup" options on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not call the `constructor`. It just creates an object without strong type  `{}` like this

```
const obj = {}
```

and put the prototype of that object to the given prototype.

You can just use `new this()` instead of the `Object.create()`

See the [**Demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20model%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20name%20%3D%20'Name'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20create()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(new%20this().name)%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20purchase%20extends%20model%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'Pruchase%20name'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20orders%20extends%20model%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'Orders%20name'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Apurchase.create()%3B%0D%0Aorders.create()%3B)

Comment: I am able to call methods, so those must copied. Is there any way for me to run the constructor?

Comment: I think you can do `new this()` instead of the `Object.create`

Answer (score 1):

It does not call the constructor, it only sets the prototype. You'd need to call it yourself

```
// Set prototype
let t = Object.create(this.prototype) as any;
// Call the constructor , this should point to the constructor
this.apply(this);
```

As others have mentioned, you should be able to do the following and have the prototype chained and the constructor called.

```
t = new this();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct something, you probably should use `new` :

```
 let t =  new this;
```

If you really want to do that manually its a bit more complicated:

```
let t = Object.create(this.prototype);
this.call(t);
```